# Is it Possible to put s9i software on an s9

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

The antminer s9i achieves slightly better stats than the s9 but uses the same hardware. Is their a way to put s9i software and firmware on an s9? Also I am used to the Linux operating system and flashing images etc. Would I be able to do this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some software engineer to do so. Because its like installing a different IOS version on iPhone. You can do it but you need someone from Apple or an expert to do that. anyway, after all, you would save only 1$/m extra since the new software saving 20 watts less than s9 software that's the only difference.

Comment: I am used to Linux operating systems and flashing images. What do you mean by a software engineer. Is there a way to get the s9i os. @Adam could I potentially install it myself?

Comment: Sorry for being busy, Yes you can install it by yourself it's not that hard, but you need to clone it first into an image then u can install it.

Comment: do you know where I could get the image for an s9i?

Comment: Not really, if I would clone it for you but I don't have s9i.

Comment: The firmwares are freely available to download from Bitmain, or are you referring to some other part of the OS that isn't normally accessible?

Comment: @KenSharp The S9i firmware hadn't yet been published to Bitmain's site in May.